# How to get coordinates of text changing at AvalonEdit control?

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-completion, sharpdevelop, avalonedit

How to know coordinates of text changing at AvalonEdit control?
It need to make code completion, using `Roslyn`.

I have `AvalonEdit` control and subscribe on TextEntering:

```
tbTextEditor.TextArea.TextEntering += TextEditor_exTtArea_TextEntering;
tbTextEditor.TextArea.TextEntered += TextEditor_TextArea_TextEntered;

 private void TextEditor_TextArea_TextEntered(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
  {
  var textChanging=e.Text;
  }
```

For example, i type dot into control;
So, `Text` value is '.';

But I have to know in which part of the world it is located?

For example, i have code like this:

```
using System;
class Test
{
 public int I=0;
 public void Completion()
 {
 var test=new Test();
 test. // here is my dot.

 test.I=10; // here is dot too.
 }
}
```

So, how to get coordinates of `test.`?

Comment: That's a very complex task, [the AvalonEdit homepage](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/html/47c58b63-f30c-4290-a2f2-881d21227446.htm), and examples in [the SharpDevelop repo](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/blob/b0838faf2d4b0c19003039cd48ae8cc49768f30f/src/AddIns/BackendBindings/TypeScript/Project/Src/TypeScriptCompletionItemProvider.cs) should get you started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found `Caret` property:

```
 var caret = tbTextEditor.TextArea.Caret;
```

Then, i should use `Caret.Offset` and make `TextSpan` (Roslyn class) to make code completion:

```
  TextSpan span = new TextSpan(caret.Offset, 1);
```